# Webkit based App using Phonegap and Sencha Touch

Tags: webkit, cordova, sencha-touch, mobile-application

I am planning to create an app which will target iOS, Android, Blackberry and Nokia S60 and Symbian 3.
I am planning to use PhoneGap using Sencha touch. I believe Blackberry does not have webkit support, so i am assuming i will have to have a separate code base for Blackberry and the same for Nokia s60 based phones. Will Blackberry and Nokia s60 devices support html5 ?
Can anyone help me as to how to proceed ahead with it.
Any help in this matter is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch will cover you for iOS, Android and BlackBerry but not for Symbian devices. But considering that Nokia has abandoned it I don't know why you'd worry about targeting it.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to go about with different form factor and resolutions ?

Comment: Ya you can use Application profiles.. check out http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Application and scroll down to Application profiles

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry uses WebKit and, for example, supports many of the WebKit css3 animations as seen here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18234/Overview_function_1176567_11.jsp

You can also read this blogpost about html5 on Blackberry: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/03/use-html5-in-your-blackberry-web-content/

Comment: From the sencha touch website: "Sencha Touch allows you to develop mobile web apps that look and feel native on iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry touch devices"